# Is there a .Net Library for DMX, specifically sACN (streaming ACN)?

Tags: .net, dmx512

I've ordered a streaming DMX (1.31) compliant controller, and I'd like to write a application to control my Christmas Lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there's no .NET library but the protocol is extremely simple to implement, especially to transmit. For the full protocol description you would need the (non-free) E1.31 standard from [PLASA/ESTA](http://tsp.plasa.org/tsp/documents/published_docs.php), however it is supported by Wireshark and [sACNView](http://sacnview.sourceforge.net/) (written in Delphi, an app I develop), and you could figure it out from the source of those two I think.

Answer (score 2):

This looks promising: [Architecture for Control Networks (ACN)](http://acn.codeplex.com) on CodePlex

Answer (score 0):

There are now several libraries that implement the sACN protocol.

[Kadmium-sACN](https://github.com/iKadmium/kadmium-sacn) is a fairly simple one that gets the job done, that I personally use.

Answer (score 0):

This library is legit too:

https://github.com/HakanL/Haukcode.sACN

It does sACN over the network well.